# Go to next frame on x position

Tags: flash, adobe

I want frame two to appear when button position is x>230.Here is code.

```
on (press) {
startDrag (this,false)
}

on (release) {
if (x> 230,00) {
gotoAndStop(3);
}
stopDrag()

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some syntax mistakes and you dragging wrong object. Here is working code

```
on (press) {
    startDrag(btn,false);
}
on (release) {
    trace(btn._x);
    if (btn._x> 230) {
        gotoAndStop(3);
}
stopDrag()
}
```

Comment: And i forgot. Your btn or mc instance name should be 'btn'.